# Opening worksheets based on Cell names in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ex

it's my first time posting on Stack Overflow. I am trying to use VBA to get it to create a new worksheet based on a cell value in sheet 1. But if the sheet already exists I need it to open that sheet instead. I'm having difficulty with this as I don't actually know the name of the sheet. I thought I could do this if I create another sheet where it stores the names of projects, using a counter. It shows me I have run-time error 91. This is the code I currently have:

```
Public Sub DailyReport()

Dim project As Range
project = Worksheets("Target Flow").Range("B3")

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

If Worksheets("Target Flow").Range("B3") <> 
Worksheets("Projects").Cells(1000, 1).Value Then

Worksheets("Target Flow").Range("B3").Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Projects").Activate
Cells(i, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))

WS.Name = project.Value

i = i + 1

Else

Worksheets("Target Flow").Activate
Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value).Activate

End If

End Sub
```

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, I'd be grateful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will scan all sheets in the active workbook to see if there is a name match, if there is it will activate it. After the loop if it doesn't see a match was made it will create it.

```
Dim targetSheetName As String
Dim targetSheetFound As Boolean
Dim sheet As Worksheet

targetSheetName = Worksheets("Target Flow").Range("B3")
targetSheetFound = False

For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If sheet.Name = targetSheetName Then

        targetSheetFound = True
        sheet.Activate

    End If

Next

If Not targetSheetFound Then

    set sheet = Sheets.Add
    sheet.Name = targetSheetName

End If
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  I edited the answer to add the "set" command in front of the sheet = Sheets.add to make sure that works as expected, too.